# TSQL - Deleting a duplicate oldest value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, sql-delete

I would like to create a SQL script to do the following:

- Identify duplicate values in the USERID field
- Next delete the record based on the oldest LOGINTIM as shown below

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use an updatable CTE for this:

```
with cte as (
    select row_number() over(partition by userid order by logintim desc) rn
    from mytable
)
delete from cte where rn > 1
```

For each `userid`, this retains the row with the most recent `logintim` and deletes the others (if any).